# Backgroundimage always under fixed header, not below

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-position

I'm having trouble with header and a background image. I have a header at the top with the following HTML.

```
<section class="blackbannerTop">
    <section class="sponsorlogos">
        <img id="sponsorlogo1" src="logo.png" alt="Sponsor logo">
    </section>
</section>
```

and then I have a section with a background image that should be placed below the header:

```
<section id="carBanner">
    <section id="siteLinks">
        <ul class="linklist">
            <li class="linklines"><a id="link1">Link 1</a></li>
            <li class="linklines"><a id="link2">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</section>
```

and here is the css for both elements:

```
.blackbannerTop {
height: 80px;
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
position: fixed;
z-index: 2;}

#carBanner {
height: 450px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(229, 229, 229, 1) 100%), url('TS12-COVER.jpg');
background-size: cover;}
```

I've tried both padding top and margin top. Margin top moves the header as well as the background image, but padding top only moves the gradient on top of the background image. So my question is how i can get the background image to display below the header, now the image starts at the top of the screen, so 90 pixels of the image are not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#carBanner {
height: 450px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(229, 229, 229, 1) 100%), url('TS12-COVER.jpg');
background-size: cover;
clear:both;
top:90px;
}
```

Comment: But can you tell me what it does exactly?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#carBanner {
    top: 80px;
    height: 450px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(229, 229, 229, 1) 100%), url('TS12-COVER.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the header to cover the first 90px of the background,which starts at the top of the screen then you need to then alter positioning to absolute and add a top value.

```
#carBanner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

    .
    . as before
    . 
}
```

Comment: I didn't want the header to cover the background, that was actually my problem, that it was covering the background.

Comment: then make the top 90px;